# Unable to use `npm run build` due to `\node_modules\tablemark\dist\index.js` being missing

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to use `npm run build` and I am unable to run is as I am being told that `\node_modules\tablemark\dist\index.js` is not found. The error is as follows:

```
> node .

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:456
      throw e;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Avin Dev\dev-hearts\node_modules\tablemark\dist\index.js'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:922:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Avin Dev\dev-hearts\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'D:\\Avin Dev\\dev-hearts\\node_modules\\tablemark\\package.json'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hearts@1.0.0 build: `node .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hearts@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\avini\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-08T07_10_51_261Z-debug.log
```

So far I have tried:

- Completely reinstalling `npm`.
- Installing tablemark separately using `npm install tablemark`

*My NPM version is: 6.14.15 and my Node version is v14.18.1*

Comment: Are you using typescript or something similar? `dist` is the folder where builded code stores (compiled from `.ts` to `.js` etc.). Error you faced with means there are no `dist` folder at all and you trying to run app before build it. For example, in typescript environment your `build` script should look like `tsc && node .` (build and then execute).

Comment: no, this is in JS and I am using build to generate some PNGs!